# Compare two files, and keep only if first word of each line is the same

Tags: bash

Here are two files where I need to eliminate the data that they do not have in common:

`a.txt`:

```
hello world 
tom tom 
super hero
```

`b.txt`:

```
hello dolly 1
tom sawyer 2
miss sunshine 3
super man 4
```

I tried:

```
grep -f a.txt b.txt >> c.txt
```

And this:

```
awk '{print $1}' test1.txt
```

because I need to check only if the first word of the line exists in the two files (even if not at the same line number).

But then what is the best way to get the following output in the new file?

output in `c.txt`:

```
hello dolly 1
tom sawyer 2
super man 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use awk where you iterate over both files:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = 1; next } a[$1]' a.txt b.txt
hello dolly 1
tom sawyer 2
super man 4
```

`NR == FNR` is only true for the first file making `{ a[$1] = 1; next }` only run on said file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to generate a sed script from the input, then use another sed to execute it.

```
sed 's=^=/^=;s= .*= /p=' a.txt | sed -nf- b.txt
```

The first sed turns your a.txt into

```
/^hello /p
/^tom /p
/^super /p
```

which prints (`p`) whenever a line contains `hello`, `tom`, or `super` at the beginning of line (`^`) followed by a space.

Comment: There is something elegant about a substitution using `=` as a delimiter. But I don't like the fact that this will potential break if column one contains meta characters.

Answer (score 0):

This combines grep, `cut` and sed with process substitution:

```
$ grep -f <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 a.txt | sed 's/^/^/') b.txt
hello dolly 1
tom sawyer 2
super man 4
```

The output of the process substitution is this (piping to `cat -A` to show spaces):

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 1 a.txt | sed 's/^/^/;s/$/ /' | cat -A
^hello $
^tom $
^super $
```

We then use this as input for `grep -f`, resulting in the above.

If your shell doesn't support process substitution, but your grep supports reading from stdin with the `-f` option (it should), you can use this instead:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 1 a.txt | sed 's/^/^/;s/$/ /' | grep -f - b.txt
hello dolly 1
tom sawyer 2
super man 4
```